# What is state Id that xtext uses while saving the resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, xtext, eclipse-orion

I am hosting xtext's orion editor using iframe in my angular application. I need to save the content written from my angular application side to a backend (Java application). Can anyone help me with what API calls or approach should I make from my angular side so that I can save the content written in the editor.

What I have already done :
1 .I tried extracting the content from the iframe from my angular side , but the data so extracted is partial as it only extracts data what is only visible through the iframe at once and not the whole content which one has to scroll to view .
2 . I tried making 'save' API calls that the xtext makes while saving, but it requires some stateId as its request body . I need to understand what is this state Id and how is it evaluated ?

I am making this call from my angular application

```
        _this.saveEditor = function(args) {
        var params = {
            requiredStateId: args.stateId
        }
        _this.saveUrl = XTEXT_URL + '/save?resource=' + args.resourceId;
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: _this.saveUrl,
            data: params
        });
    };
```

my request body is :

```
{"requiredStateId":"-80000000"}
```

And this is the state Id i am obtaining by  making a prior load api call which.returns state Id in its response.

Comment: "What I have already done" => can you add some code for that

Comment: simply calling save from the client to the server does not work? https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-web/blob/master/org.eclipse.xtext.web.example.jetty/src/main/webapp/orion-statemachine-resource.html

Comment: @christianDietrich didnot work

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example? Did you try to debug the backend

Comment: @christianDietrich we intend to use the same save api but how to call it from angular client side application?

Comment: @christianDietrich and Rakeschand I have updated the question. Please have a look

Comment: the required state id is used to make sure there are no conflicting request hickups. it is equal to the last stateId you got in the servers responses.

Answer (score 0):

may this snipped can help you, i dont know how you can wire this up with your stuff though

```
require(["orion/code_edit/built-codeEdit-amd"], function() {
        require(["xtext/xtext-orion"], function(xtext) {
            var editors = xtext.createEditor({
                baseUrl: baseUrl,
                syntaxDefinition: "xtext-resources/generated/mydsl-syntax"
            }).done(function(editorViewer) {
                $("#save-button").click(function() {
                    editorViewer.xtextServices.saveResource();
                });
                $("#log-button").click(function() {
                    console.log(editorViewer.xtextServices.editorContext.getServerState());
                });
            });

        });
    });
```

where i do the simple log you can query and then call save manually.